# How can I line up this button better with the content in the middle? It seems off center to me:

Tags: html, css, css-grid

margin-top on the button itself may be the answer but it feels wrong to me. If it is hopefully an answer will confirm. What is the best solution to lower the button a smidgen?

The codepen for extra context: https://codepen.io/AdanRod133/full/WNZEYJX

```css
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  background-color: coral;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 300px 115px;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2D8C9E;
}

.btn-learn {
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 125px;
}

.body-title {
  font-size: 1.15em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  justify-self: center;
}

.text-body {
  font-size: 16px;
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="body-title">
      Startup
    </h3>
    <p class="text-body">Create Websites Online using the Startup Boostrap 5 builder</p>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-learn">Learn More <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share image of what you want?

Comment: https://files.reallygoodemails.com/emails/black-friday-on-designmodo-30-discount-for-a-limited-time.png

Im trying to create the bottom section using css grid in order to get practice in and understand grid better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the result: https://codepen.io/AdanRod133/full/WNZEYJX

```
.btn-learn{
position: relative;
height: 40px;
border: none;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #00A57F;
color: #D8D7DF;
height: 2.5em;
padding: 10px 25px;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
justify-self: end;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

I got rid of the width and set the button to inline-block. Then added some padding.

I wanted to make something css-grid only in order to get more practice in.
Working with the padding as well as adding grid gap allowed the items to
sit where I wanted them to.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrapped your button in a flex container and used its property align-items: center

There were also some styling changes I have made

you have made three column in grid with 100px 300px and 100px

but assigned the button with width: 125px that will make the styling error

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <div class="content">
        <h3 class="body-title">
        Startup
    </h3>
    <p class="text-body">Create Websites Online using the Startup Boostrap 5 builder</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
    <button class="btn btn-learn">Learn More <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
body{
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
}

.container{
    background-color: coral;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 300px 125px;
    grid-row-gap: 1em;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 40%;
    height: 90px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #2D8C9E;
}

.btn-learn{
/*  justify-self: center; */
/*  align-self: center; */
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
/*  margin-top: 16px; */
}

.body-title{
    font-size: 1.15em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    justify-self: center;
}

.text-body{
    font-size: 16px;
    grid-column: 3 / 5;
}

.button-container
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should restructure your `div` in a better way. For example, I think you are looking for content box like this:

[image]

I would suggest you to use Bootstrap if you are new to front-end web development.

Here is an example of how your Bootstrap-5 code looks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #2d8c9e;
      }

      .btn-learn {
        justify-self: center;
        align-self: center;
        height: 40px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
        width: 125px;
      }

      .body-title {
        font-size: 1.15em;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        font-weight: bold;
        justify-self: center;
      }

      .text-body {
        font-size: 16px;
        grid-column: 3 / 5;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
          <img src="" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
          <h3 class="body-title">Startup</h3>
          <p class="text-body">Create Websites Online using the Startup Boostrap 5 builder</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
          <button class="btn btn-learn">Learn More <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `css` file .

```
    body {
        font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .container {
        background-color: coral;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap:no-wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        width: 80%;
        height: 100px;
        padding: 10px;
     }

    img {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #2D8C9E;
    }

    .content {
        padding:0% 2%;
    }

    .body-title {
        font-size: 1.15em;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        font-weight: bold;
        justify-self: center;
     }

    .text-body {
        font-size: 16px;
        grid-column: 3 / 5;
    } 

    .btn-learn {
        height: 40px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
        width: 125px;
    }
```

And html file like this

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="" alt="">
      <div class="content">
        <h3 class="body-title">
          Startup
        </h3>
        <p class="text-body">
            Create Websites Online using the Startup Boostrap 5 builder
        </p>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-learn">
          Learn More 
             <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
```